# Create database for fabric_lakehouse is not permitted using Apache Spark in Microsoft Fabric

Tags: apache-spark, data-lakehouse, microsoft-fabric

I followed the instruction [Use delta tables in Apache Spark](https://microsoftlearning.github.io/mslearn-fabric/Instructions/Labs/03-delta-lake.html)

but when I try to save the tables into lakehouse, I got below message. I got the similar error message when following "Lakehouse tutorial introduction" when trying to read fact_sale table. Did I miss some permission settings?

`Create database for fabric_lakehouse is not permitted using Apache Spark in Microsoft Fabric.`

I checked all the settings but can't find any in Fabric workspace.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Full message: 
Error Details
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Create database for *** is not permitted using Apache Spark in Microsoft Fabric. )
Error Code
InvalidTable

Comment: yep..I put the same question to the learning  doc github but seems like they can't answer that. just said it seems like a tenant level permission issue. no idea what to check next :(

Comment: I tried with a new free Power BI free account and don't have the issue. It must be a tenant permission setting but just don't know where/what to check/adjust.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `.coalesce(1)`. Without this, the system tries to create multiple tables and fails.

```
df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").format("delta").saveAsTable("mytable")
```

Comment: don't think that's the issue as when I created a new tenant, it doesn't run into this error.

Answer (score 0):

Running into the same issue, strangely only when I have not saved the notebook with a custom name though.

I tried the coalesce (1) workaround, but ran into a myriad of new issues.

Accordingly, my rather unfortunate recommendation is to create a new notebook, do not rename it, and proceed from there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No luck with that. I got the error message even if just using "Load to table" option from the file. maybe it's firewall related setting but no idea where to check

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue. Resolved by re-attaching a lakehouse , so you might have a multiple lakehouse within your workspace and notebook can be run on any of them.

click on the name of lakehouse and remove all lakehouses. Once removed click on add lakehouse and add the lakehouse again. this is should resolve the issue.

[image]

Comment: I tried that but there is no luck. I also tried to create a new clean workspace and it runs into the same issue. Feels like a permission thing as I didn't get the error when I sign up a new account. However, obvisouly can't do that with work account. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can add the existing or new lakehouse which is in the data source. This lets it know where to put the table.